# Github api getting commits

Tags: javascript, commit, github-api

I'm trying to list commits of an repositories and I'm finding success with some repos and with others it gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null".

Right now the code works like it should, but when i switch var i to "reddit/cabot-alert-slack" it gives me this error

code:

```
    var i = "reddit/IndicatorFastScroll"; //githubusername/repository

    async function getCommits() {
        //const test = "https://api.github.com/repos/"
        const test = "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=repo:"
        const testurl = test.concat(i);
        const pvm = " author-date:2000-03-01..2019-12-02"

        const url = testurl.concat(pvm)
        const headers = {
            "Accept" : "application/vnd.github.cloak-preview"
        }
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            "method" : "GET",
            "headers" : headers
        })

        const link = response.headers.get("link")
        const links = link.split(",")
        const urls = links.map(a=> {
            return {
                url: a.split(";")[0].replace(">","").replace("<",""),
                title:a.split(";")[1]
            }
        })
        const result = await response.json()
        result.items.slice(0,10).forEach(i=>{
      //  result.items.forEach(i=>{
            const img = document.createElement("img")
            img.src = i.author.avatar_url;
            img.style.width="32px"
            img.style.height="32px"
            const anchor = document.createElement("a")
            anchor.href = i.html_url;
            anchor.textContent = i.commit.message;
            divResult.appendChild(img)
            divResult.appendChild(anchor)
            divResult.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have multiple calls to `split`. Which one is triggering the error?

Comment: It is the first one that is triggering the error

Comment: I'm guessing maybe the response headers don't include a `link` key? Have you inspected the response in this case?

Comment: Thank you got it solved. removed const urls function and got it working

Comment: Is the `link` header only present when there are multiple pages of objects? I was reading this https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination and I noticed the IndicatorFastScroll repo has more than 30 commits, while cabot-alert-slack only has two commits.